# Storage Concerning Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants

I'm having trouble understanding the following code:

```
    const char *suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"}
```

I don't understand what is stored in the array suit, are they pointers? And if so, where are the strings stored?

Also, is the pointer constant, or the array constant?

I would appreciate a full detailed explanation of this code, and what is going on in memory!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We learn a lot by using [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+char+%2Asuit%5B4%5D+).  This is what it tells us about `suit`:

> declare suit as array 4 of pointer to const char

So:

- the array contains 4 pointers.
- each pointer points at a `char` (in this case, the first character of each string).
- the pointers are not `const`, and neither is the array.

The strings are *literals*; where they are stored is implementation-specific.

In ASCII art:

```
              "Clubs"
               ^
               |  "Spades"
               |   ^
               |   |
     +---+---+---+---+
suit |   |   |   |   |
     +---+---+---+---+
       |   |
       |   v
       |  "Diamonds"
       v
      "Hearts"
```

Note that `suit` itself is **not** a pointer; it's the name of the array.

Comment: "and neither is the array" well, what does it mean for an array to be const?

Answer (score 1):

`const char *` is a string type since strings are just arrays of characters. This means you have an array of `const char *` (strings). The strings themselves are constant and are stored in the .data section of your file binary when compiled. Hence the data pointed to by the pointer is constant.